# Why is the preposition "in" omitted in "it has risen to the occasion the past two playoff runs"

Tags: prepositions

I came across a sentence from an [old newspaper sports reporting](https://www.newspapers.com/newspage/123674513/):

> Bench strength could be suspect, but **it has risen to the occasion the past two playoff runs**.

Why is it not *it has risen to the occasion **in** the past two playoff runs.*? I thought a preposition was required here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of understood phrases which might be supplied by the mind of a native speaker:

> ...over the past two runs
>
> ...in the past two runs
>
> ...in the course of the past two runs
>
> ...during the past two runs
>
> ...across the past two runs

Any (adverbial) prepositional phrase which expresses behavior over the passage of time would make sense here. Different ones would predominate depending on whether one was in the UK or the US.

Comment: The regional variations in language make a significant difference regarding accepted usage.  This is clealry an American phrase, it's unlikley this would be used by a non-American speaker.  However as American culture is very pervasive the idioms of American English tend to proliferate over time.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't say "in" because it doesn't mean "in." It's no different than saying:

> "It has risen to the occasion twice."
>
> "It has risen to the occasion two times."
>
> "It has risen to the occasion the past two times."
>
> "What past two times?"
>
> "The past two playoff runs."
>
> "It has risen to the occasion the past two playoff runs."